# Execute Makefile specific commands in rule section

Tags: makefile

Suupose I have an `include` directive:

`include dep/dep.mk`

To include other required information for my build. However, I only want it to be included after certain targets have been built. How can I do that?

For example:

```
test: foo.c bar.c
     include dep/dep.mk
```

In this case, `include` won't work because Make understand it as a shell command.

Comment: Are there any objective reasons of including it "after certain targets have been built"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  If you're using GNU make of sufficiently modern vintage you can use `$(eval include dep/dep.mk)`, BUT note that the included makefile *cannot* define any rules.  Once make starts building targets, no new rules/targets can be defined, even with `$(eval ...)`.

The best you can do is have those commands that want to include that file invoke make recursively such that the sub-make will include the file.

However I agree with Eldar; you need to reconsider your requirements.  Perhaps if you explained why you want to do that we could give better advice.

Comment: Because the included file is in another git submodule, and the Makefile includes needed files from that submodule. However, the submodule can only be downloaded once make invokes the needed rule. I think I have no way but to perform "git submodule update init-- module" for that module before includes the files then.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution with `eval` works. All I need is to call `include` directive in a rule, and `eval` did the job for me.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry about this but I tested it again and it didn't work. I guess I have to tell the maintainer to change the Makefile.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you need a recursive invocation of make.  Have a rule in your top-level makefile that can invoke the rule to obtain the submodule from git, then recursively invoke make in a mode that reads the content of the sub-module.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do you can use make's built-in support for included makefile rebuilds.  If you include a file and make can find a rule to rebuild it, make will automatically rebuild it and re-exec itself.  So if you write a rule to create the dep/dep.mk file, that obtains the git submodule, it should just work.